# Streaming delimited files using Spring Cloud Data Flow

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to load a tab delimited file from a remote Linux server and load it in to Postgres database using Spring Cloud Data Flow, but stuck on choosing appropriate source and sink.

For source, I tried using File source as well SFTP source. File source doesn't seem to have any option to connect to a remote Linux server and SFTP source has those options, but it mostly appears to be used for transferring files rather than parsing it.

For Sink, I have installed PgCopy sink and planning to use it to load the data. I would like to know if this would be right sink to go for my use case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [sftp source](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/sftp/tree/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-sftp) with `--mode lines` to split the file content by line, and send a message for each line.

Then, you can parse each line using a CSV parser. I did [a processor](https://github.com/dapicard/scdf-apps/tree/master/csv-to-map) that is able to split each line to a java.util.Map using jackson-csv given [a configuration](https://github.com/dapicard/scdf-config/blob/master/adresse-ban.yml). I think you could use it as a base for your own, or use it as I show it in [this video](https://youtu.be/XqB3ex34JRg) (in french).

To finish, you can publish each map to your pgsql table using [jdbc-sink](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/jdbc/tree/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-jdbc) as I did in the given video with [this configuration](https://github.com/dapicard/scdf-config/blob/master/adresse.yml).